# CakePhp 3.4 User table records not getting

Tags: php, cakephp-3.4

I am trying to fetch all records from users table as below code:

```
$this->loadModel('User');
$users_list = $this->User->find('all');
pr($users_list);
```

but the resulting page shows like below:

```
Cake\ORM\Query Object
(
  [_hasFields:protected] => 
  [_autoFields:protected] => 
  [_hydrate:protected] => 1
```

...
continued with lot of lines

is I am writing anything wrong?... 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Will you elaborate this questions little more..How is the relations look like ? What is the name of the table and structure of table ?

Answer (score 1):

For CakePhp3 that should be:

```
$this->loadModel('Users');
$users_list = $this->Users->find('all');
```

You can also use TableRegistry:

```
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
$usersTable= TableRegistry::get('Users');
$users_list = $usersTable->find('all');
```

See Here:

1.[Loading Model in CakePhp3](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#loading-additional-models)

2.[Using TableRegistry](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#the-query-object)

What you have done is used for CakePhp2.

Comment: I am used your code:
   written below loaded before class 
    use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
   
  written below code in controller function:

    $usersTable= TableRegistry::get('Users');
    $users_list = $usersTable->find('all');
but no change...getting same result

Comment: Given that the output shows that `$users_list` is a query object, it looks like the OP is actually operating with a proper table object. Not following the naming conventions does work, even if it's not recommended (could have also been just a typo in the example maybe). The actual problem seems to be that the OP doesn't know about the new ORM basics with regards to query objects, lazy evaluation, etc.